# Delete rows containing Numeric characters

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, spyder, data-cleaning

I have been working on a dataset which contains unigrams related to products. Within the dataframe we have unigrams like cadbury9gm or 100gmdoritos, SO I would like to delete the entire row containing names like these i.e containing numerical values to make dataframe more clean so that I can proceed further because I have to classify products in categories and sub-categories. Is there a way to do delete rows containing numerical characters ? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried pandas indexing with [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bogus_data = {
    'Name': ['Acme', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Loren', 'Ipsum'],
    'Label': ['abc', '3ds', 'cba', 'b3ewq', 'asdf'],
    'Value': np.random.rand(5)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(bogus_data, columns=['Name', 'Label', 'Value'])
df = df[~df["Label"].str.contains(r'[0-9]')]

print(df)
```

The result from printing this dataframe is

```
    Name Label     Value
0   Acme   abc  0.574412
2    Bar   cba  0.354460
4  Ipsum  asdf  0.047170
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
testdf

    Name    Value
0   Name1   4409
1   Name2   SomeVal
2   Name3   26Text73
3   Name4   SomeVal2
4   Name5   2123Text
5   Name6   Text1904
6   Name7   1Text747
7   Name8   145Text7

# Add a column that validates your contains digit condition
testdf['HasDigit'] = testdf['Value'].map(lambda x: True if any(i.isdigit() for i in str(x)) else False)
testdf
    Name    Value       HasDigit
0   Name1   4409        True
1   Name2   SomeVal     False
2   Name3   26Text73    True
3   Name4   SomeVal2    True
4   Name5   2123Text    True
5   Name6   Text1904    True
6   Name7   1Text747    True
7   Name8   145Text7    True

# Finally retain the ones with value False in 'HasDigit' columns
testdf = testdf[testdf['HasDigit'] == False]
testdf  

    Name    Value       HasDigit
1   Name2   SomeVal     False
```

You can drop the 'HasDigit' column later on.

This will work perfectly if you are looking to filter on the basis of values from single column. However if there are multiple columns involved, you could create a new column which concatenates the string value of all the columns under consideration. Here's an example:

```
testdf['NewCol'] = testdf['Col1'].astype(str) + testdf['Col2'].astype(str) + ... + testdf['Coln'].astype(str)
```

Once you have this new column you can run the same lambda function on that.

Hope this helps